# ORA-00931: missing identifier when using CASE in XMLELEMENT function

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have the below code snippet that generates an XML file and it works fine:

```
SELECT  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("tns:Podmiot1",
                        (SELECT xmlconcat(XMLELEMENT("tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu", 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:NIP", regexp_replace(jgzzvtg.jg_info_v7, '[^0-9]+', '')), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:PelnaNazwa", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v8))
                                        , XMLELEMENT("tns:AdresPodmiotu", 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:KodKraju", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Wojewodztwo", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v11),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Powiat", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v12),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Gmina", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v13),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Ulica", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v14), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:NrDomu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v15),
                                                    CASE WHEN jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16 IS NOT NULL THEN XMLELEMENT("etd:NrLokalu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16) END, --modified for bug 28298307
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Miejscowosc", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v17), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:KodPocztowy", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v18)))
                        FROM    jg_zz_vat_trx_gt jgzzvtg
                        WHERE   jgzzvtg.jg_info_v1 = 'H')))
FROM dual;
```

However, I am required to add a quick logic to the tag `tns:AdresPodmiotu`. it should appear as `tns:AdresPodmiotu2` if the value of `jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10` is not "PL".
The below code snippet works fine:

```
SELECT  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("tns:Podmiot1",
                        (SELECT xmlconcat(XMLELEMENT("tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu", 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:NIP", regexp_replace(jgzzvtg.jg_info_v7, '[^0-9]+', '')), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:PelnaNazwa", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v8)),
                                                    (CASE WHEN jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then XMLELEMENT ("tns:AdresPodmiotu",
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:KodKraju" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10) ,
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Wojewodztwo" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v11),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Powiat" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v12),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Gmina" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v13) ,
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Ulica" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v14),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:NrDomu" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v15),
                                                         Case When jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16 is not null Then XMLELEMENT ( "etd:NrLokalu" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16) End, --modified for bug 28298307
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Miejscowosc" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v17),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:KodPocztowy" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v18)
                                                        ) 
                                                    else XMLELEMENT ("tns:AdresPodmiotu2",
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:KodKraju" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10) ,
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Wojewodztwo" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v11),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Powiat" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v12),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Gmina" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v13) ,
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Ulica" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v14),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:NrDomu" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v15),
                                                         Case When jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16 is not null Then XMLELEMENT ( "etd:NrLokalu" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16) End, --modified for bug 28298307
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:Miejscowosc" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v17),
                                                         XMLELEMENT ( "etd:KodPocztowy" , jgzzvtg.jg_info_v18)
                                                    ) end))
                        FROM    jg_zz_vat_trx_gt jgzzvtg
                        WHERE   jgzzvtg.jg_info_v1 = 'H')))
FROM dual;
```

However, I wanted to make it a bit shorter since the only thing that will really change is `tns:AdresPodmiotu` to `tns:AdresPodmiotu2`, I tried to do the below query, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("tns:Podmiot1",
                        (SELECT xmlconcat(XMLELEMENT("tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu", 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:NIP", regexp_replace(jgzzvtg.jg_info_v7, '[^0-9]+', '')), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:PelnaNazwa", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v8))
                                        , XMLELEMENT( (case when jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then "tns:AdresPodmiotu" else "tns:AdresPodmiotu2" end) , 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:KodKraju", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Wojewodztwo", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v11),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Powiat", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v12),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Gmina", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v13),
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Ulica", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v14), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:NrDomu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v15),
                                                    CASE WHEN jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16 IS NOT NULL THEN XMLELEMENT("etd:NrLokalu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16) END, --modified for bug 28298307
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:Miejscowosc", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v17), 
                                                    XMLELEMENT("etd:KodPocztowy", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v18)))
                        FROM    jg_zz_vat_trx_gt jgzzvtg
                        WHERE   jgzzvtg.jg_info_v1 = 'H')))
FROM dual;
```

It's giving me an `ORA-00931: missing identifier` error. Is there any other way I can write this piece of code the shortest way possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this by encasing it in another `SELECT FROM DUAL` statement, then using `EVALNAME` to get the Tag:

```
SELECT  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("tns:Podmiot1",
                    (SELECT xmlconcat(XMLELEMENT("tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu", 
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:NIP", regexp_replace(jgzzvtg.jg_info_v7, '[^0-9]+', '')), 
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:PelnaNazwa", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v8))
                                    -- , XMLELEMENT( (case when jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then "tns:AdresPodmiotu" else "tns:AdresPodmiotu2" end) ,  -- this is the old code
                                    , XMLELEMENT( evalname(select case when jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then 'tns:AdresPodmiotu' else 'tns:AdresPodmiotu2' end 
                                                           from   dual),                                                
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:KodKraju", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10), 
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:Wojewodztwo", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v11),
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:Powiat", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v12),
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:Gmina", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v13),
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:Ulica", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v14), 
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:NrDomu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v15),
                                                CASE WHEN jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16 IS NOT NULL THEN XMLELEMENT("etd:NrLokalu", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v16) END, --modified for bug 28298307
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:Miejscowosc", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v17), 
                                                XMLELEMENT("etd:KodPocztowy", jgzzvtg.jg_info_v18)))
                    FROM    jg_zz_vat_trx_gt jgzzvtg
                    WHERE   jgzzvtg.jg_info_v1 = 'H')))
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part of your failing query appears to be this expression:

```sql
XMLELEMENT( (case when jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then "tns:AdresPodmiotu" else "tns:AdresPodmiotu2" end)
    -- ...
)
```

You can specify the element name in `XMLELEMENT` by either specifying an identifier, as you are doing in your working queries, or as `EVALNAME` followed by an expression.  You need to use the latter, so try the following instead:

```sql
XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME (case when jgzzvtg.jg_info_v10 = 'PL' then 'tns:AdresPodmiotu' else 'tns:AdresPodmiotu2' end)
    -- ...
)
```

Note that I've changed `tns:AdresPodmiotu` and `tns:AdresPodmiotu2` to single-quoted strings.

Comment: unfortunately, while this syntax is correct and it compiled, it didn't work. It resulted into an empty XML file due to the single-quoted strings, while the double-quoted strings result into an Error.

Comment: @MigsIsip: odd, I couldn't reproduce that behaviour.  Nonetheless, glad to see you've got it working.